# Добавить действие QAction в QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlineedit, qaction

Не работает добавление действий в `QLineEdit`:

```
action = QAction(QIcon(self.style().standardPixmap(
        QStyle.SP_MessageBoxCritical)), '')
self.addAction(action, QLineEdit.TrailingPosition)
```

Аналогичный код на C++ работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QAction, QApplication, QStyle, QLineEdit)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit() 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.statusBar()

        actionQuit = QAction(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MessageBoxCritical), 'Quit', self)
        self.lineEdit.addAction(actionQuit, 2)

        actionQuit.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        actionQuit.setStatusTip('Закрыть приложение')
        actionQuit.triggered.connect(self.quit)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Menu')
        fileMenu.addAction(actionQuit)  

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit dialog')
        self.show()

    def quit(self):
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, не указал `self` в конструкторе `QAction`.